# Automatic printing through IE6

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-6

We have a requirement to auto print dockets from a webpage.

We are developing a stock control application using ASP.NET, MVC2 using IE6

Scenerio is as follows:

Once the user has completed the order, a docket should be automatically printed. At the moment, I am using Javascript command  "window.print();" method however the print dialog button is displayed.

Is there a way to stop the print dialog button from showing and the docket will be automatically printed?

Comment: Developing a new web application in 2010 that's based on IE6 should be literally a felony.

Comment: It's a good thing you can't. Imagine getting a pop-up ad that sends 500 copies of some nekkid ladies to the printer whilst you're not looking.

Comment: Pointy, We have gone down that path. We developers/contractors have pleaded with upper management. When your working on XP sp2 using Office XP things around here don't move fast I can assure you.

Comment: Is it going to print that on the user's side or your side? If it's on the user's side you NEED a printer dialog to have the user select the printer he wants to use. If you're in an office there can be more than one printers and the user should be able to select which one he wants. If it's on your side, you can invoke the command using a POST or GET request with AJAX and execute the printing using server-side methods.

Answer (score 4):

No way to do this directly, but if you install an ActiveX control (in other words, run your own code in the browser), then you can do whatever you want.

Note that Microsoft is strongly discouraging the use of IE6.  Here's part of the [campaign which compares IE6 to 9 year old milk](http://www.microsoft.com/australia/technet/ie8milk/Default.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Nope, this is related to browser and you can not print directly. You need to press the **Print** button on that dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](http://justtalkaboutweb.com/2008/05/09/javascript-print-bypass-printer-dialog-in-ie-and-firefox/). It is probably what you need. It has solutions for silent-printing in both IE and Firefox. However it always requires the user to tweak his browser settings. This is so that web pages you visit don't automatically silently send print commands to your printer.

P.S. this would make a very nice prank!

Comment: Stages, thanks for the link, where I am currently contracted to, a government organisation and the machines are locked down, it is not easily accessible to the browser settings, You have to put in a request form etc joys of the bureaucratic process.

Comment: You need to fill that request form to tell them to change browsers cause IE6 and that government data are vulnerable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to prevent the print dialog box in the browser.

If you could make it so that your web app could create files on an internal network file server, then the file server could be set up to print any files dropped into its directory.  There appear to be some software solutions for this second half: http://www.google.com/search?q=automatically+print+file+in+directory